# Как сделать миграцию без потери данных?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Добрый день.
Есть модель

```
class MyModel
{
  int Id { get; set; }
  int Prop1 { get; set; }
  int Prop2 { get; set; }
  int Prop3 { get; set; }
}
```

ее нужно разбить на 2:

```
class NewModel1
{
  int Id { get; set; }
  int Prop1 { get; set; }
  int NewProp { get; set; }
}
```

и

```
class NewModel2
{
  int Id { get; set; }
  int Prop2 { get; set; }
  int NewProp { get; set; }
}
```

если в `vs` командой `add-migration` делать, то там просто все удаляется и новые добавляются, а хотелось бы сохранив данные, разделать `Prop1` и `Prop2` на новые модели (с добавлением своих новых), `Prop3` удалить.
`ASP.NET MVC 5`.

Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Отредактируйте тот код, который генерирует `add-migration`: пусть сначала добавляются новые таблицы, а только потом - удаляется старая.

Теперь между этими операциями можно вставить такой запрос:

```
insert into NewModel1
select Id, Prop1
from MyModel;

insert into NewModel2
select Id, Prop2
from MyModel;
```

Тут еще может быть проблема с колонкой Id: наверняка она - `IDENTITY`, а значит, ей значение в операторе `INSERT` так просто не указать. Тут есть два решения. Решение первое - добавить перед оператором `INSERT` конструкцию `SET IDENTITY_INSERT NewModel1 ON` - а после оператора `INSERT` - `SET IDENTITY_INSERT NewModel1 OFF`. Для `NewModel2` - так же.

Решение второе - не создавать эту колонку как `IDENTITY` сразу, а поменять ее тип уже после выполнения запроса.

PS точно уже не помню, но у EF были также проблемы с порядком выполнения операций: операции не всегда выполняются в том же порядке, в котором они указаны в файле миграции. Если у вас возникнет такая проблема - просто разбейте одну миграцию на несколько.